# How to get the cumulative distribution function with NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I want to create a CDF with NumPy, my code is the next:

```
histo = np.zeros(4096, dtype = np.int32)
for x in range(0, width):
   for y in range(0, height):
      histo[data[x][y]] += 1
      q = 0 
   cdf = list()
   for i in histo:
      q = q + i
      cdf.append(q)
```

I am walking by the array but take a long time the program execution. There is a built function with this feature, isn't?

Comment: Also see [empirical distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your code is doing, but if you have `hist` and `bin_edges` arrays returned by `numpy.histogram` you can use `numpy.cumsum` to generate a cumulative sum of the histogram contents.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(np.random.randint(0,10,100), normed=True)
>>> bin_edges
array([ 0. ,  0.9,  1.8,  2.7,  3.6,  4.5,  5.4,  6.3,  7.2,  8.1,  9. ])
>>> hist
array([ 0.14444444,  0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.1       ,  0.1       ,
        0.14444444,  0.14444444,  0.08888889,  0.03333333,  0.13333333])
>>> np.cumsum(hist)
array([ 0.14444444,  0.25555556,  0.36666667,  0.46666667,  0.56666667,
        0.71111111,  0.85555556,  0.94444444,  0.97777778,  1.11111111])
```

Comment: However, this introduces a binning step that would not be necessary for a cumulative distribution.

Comment: "This keyword, `normed` is deprecated in Numpy 1.6 due to confusing/buggy behavior. It will be removed in Numpy 2.0. "There is a bug in the code if bin is not in `[0,1]`. Add x=np.cumsum(hist); x=(x - x.min()) / x.ptp()

Comment: @hans_meine Exactly. Any better solution for this?

Comment: @becko Dan's reply above contains both a histogram-based and an "exact" solution ("method 2").

Comment: Ah yes I missed that. Thanks @hans_meine

Answer (score 107):

Using a histogram is one solution but it involves binning the data. This is not necessary for plotting a CDF of empirical data. Let `F(x)` be the count of how many entries are less than `x` then it goes up by one, exactly where we see a measurement. Thus, if we sort our samples then at each point we increment the count by one (or the fraction by 1/N) and plot one against the other we will see the "exact" (i.e. un-binned) empirical CDF.

A following code sample demonstrates the method

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
Z = np.random.normal(size = N)
# method 1
H,X1 = np.histogram( Z, bins = 10, normed = True )
dx = X1[1] - X1[0]
F1 = np.cumsum(H)*dx
#method 2
X2 = np.sort(Z)
F2 = np.array(range(N))/float(N)

plt.plot(X1[1:], F1)
plt.plot(X2, F2)
plt.show()
```

It outputs the following

[image]

Comment: as per numpy.histogram docs : __normed__ is equivalent to the __density__ argument, but produces incorrect results for unequal bin widths. Changed in version 1.15.0: DeprecationWarnings are actually emitted.

Comment: How would you deal with exact duplicate values in `Z`?

Answer (score 7):

update for numpy version 1.9.0. user545424's answer does not work in 1.9.0. This works:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
>>> hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(arr, density=True)
>>> hist = array([ 0.16666667,  0.15555556,  0.15555556,  0.05555556,  0.08888889,
    0.08888889,  0.07777778,  0.04444444,  0.18888889,  0.08888889])
>>> hist
array([ 0.1       ,  0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.08888889,  0.08888889,
    0.15555556,  0.11111111,  0.13333333,  0.1       ,  0.11111111])
>>> bin_edges
array([ 0. ,  0.9,  1.8,  2.7,  3.6,  4.5,  5.4,  6.3,  7.2,  8.1,  9. ])
>>> np.diff(bin_edges)
array([ 0.9,  0.9,  0.9,  0.9,  0.9,  0.9,  0.9,  0.9,  0.9,  0.9])
>>> np.diff(bin_edges)*hist
array([ 0.09,  0.1 ,  0.1 ,  0.08,  0.08,  0.14,  0.1 ,  0.12,  0.09,  0.1 ])
>>> cdf = np.cumsum(hist*np.diff(bin_edges))
>>> cdf
array([ 0.15,  0.29,  0.43,  0.48,  0.56,  0.64,  0.71,  0.75,  0.92,  1.  ])
>>>
```

Comment: user12287, I feel weird editing other people's answers. Besides, different answers for different versions.

Answer (score 5):

To complement Dan's solution.
In the case where there are several identical values in your sample, you can use numpy.unique :

```
Z = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,8])
X, F = np.unique(Z, return_index=True)
F=F/X.size

plt.plot(X, F)
```

Comment: That gives you values of `F` that are greater than 1. Perhaps you meant to use `F = F / float(F.max())` (also bear in mind that integer division would  cause problems for people using Python 2x).

Comment: This answer is old, thank you for your comments and answers. I have seen in each answer my rudimentary approach from three years ago.

Comment: @Alex this is not quite correct since it should go up by more than 1/N for the entries which are there more than once. You're correct my solution will only be correct for the last one of such occurances but it will plot correctly.

Comment: In principle you are using counts, but python uses zero based indexing in F, so perhaps you meant `(F + 1) / (F[-1] + 1)`

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers either resort to using a histogram, or don't handle duplicate values nicely/correctly (either ignoring duplicate values, or yielding a CDF that contains multiple y-values for the same x-value). I suggest the following method:

```
x, CDF_counts = np.unique(data, return_counts = True)
y = np.cumsum(CDF_counts)/np.sum(CDF_counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor improvement to [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30460089/17709794)'s "Exact" #2 method. I believe the ecdf of the first observation should not be 0, the last one should be 1, also eCDFs are often visualized as step functions (all three are mostly irrelevant for large `n`).

There was an unanswered question about duplicates, the matplotlib visualize them well, but here is a way to remove them:

```py
x = np.array([3, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 2, 2.5])
# x = np.random.normal(size = 100)

x = np.sort(x)
n = x.shape[0]

# original
y = np.arange(n)/n
plt.plot(x, y, label='original')
plt.plot(x, y, '.', color='tab:red', label='original')

# step (0, 1]
y_step = np.arange(1,n+1)/n
plt.step(x, y_step, where='post', label='step')

# no duplicates
x_unique, inds = np.unique(x, return_index=True)
y_unique = [y_[-1] for y_ in  np.split(y_step, inds[1:])]
plt.step(x_unique, y_unique, '--', where='post', label='step (unique)')
plt.plot(x_unique, y_unique, '.', color='tab:brown', label='step (unique)')

plt.ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure if there is a ready-made answer, the exact thing to do is to define a function like:

```
def _cdf(x,data):
    return(sum(x>data))
```

This will be pretty fast.