# Is there a standard way to work with numerical probability density functions in Python?

Tags: python, random, numpy, scipy, distribution

I have a continuous random variable given by its density distribution function or by cumulative probability distribution function.

The distribution functions are not analytical. They are given numerically (for example as a list of (x,y) values).

One of the things that I would like to do with these distributions is to find a convolution of two of them (to have a distribution of a sum of two random properties).

I do not want to write my own function for that if there is already something standard and tested. Does anybody know if it is the case?

Comment: This post may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640759/how-to-get-the-cumulative-distribution-function-with-numpy

Answer (score 4):

How about `numpy.convolve`?  It takes two arrays, rather than two functions, which seems ideal for your use.  I'll also mention the ECDF function in the `statsmodels` package in case you really want to turn your observations into (step) functions.