# How to get CDF point evaluations in place using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, cdf

I have an array of random samples from a normal distribution where I want to evaluate the CDF of each element in place

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)
arr
array([-0.03960733, -0.58329607, -1.55133923, ..., -0.94473672,
        1.24757701, -0.66197476])
```

I know I could do this using `scipy.stats.norm().cdf`, but I am restricted to only using numpy.

I have found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30460089/4139143) that outlines how to do something similar using `numpy.histogram` and `numpy.cumsum`. How can I extend this (using only numpy) to evaluate the CDF of each element in place, so the output array is as below

```
from scipy import stats
stats.norm().cdf(arr)
array([0.48420309, 0.279847  , 0.06041021, ..., 0.17239665, 0.893907  ,
       0.2539937 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this can be achieved using `numpy.argsort()` twice to get the ranks of each random sample in `arr`. There is some round-off error however

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)
arr
array([-0.24822623, -0.49071664, -0.75405418, ..., -0.59249804,
       -0.9140224 ,  0.18904534])


x = arr.argsort().argsort()  # ranks of each entry in `arr`
y = np.arange(len(arr)) / len(arr)
numpy_cdfs = y[x]  # sort `y` by ranks

numpy_cdfs 
array([0.3973, 0.307 , 0.2204, ..., 0.2713, 0.1745, 0.5696])
```

If we compare to scipy, we need to set the absolute tolerance to 1e-2 (quite high).

```
from scipy import stats
scipy_cdfs = stats.norm().cdf(arr)

scipy_cdfs
array([0.40197969, 0.31181344, 0.22540834, ..., 0.27675857, 0.18035254,
       0.57497136])

np.allclose(numpy_cdfs, scipy_cdfs, atol=1e-2)
True
```

This error will decrease the more samples we have.