# Easier way to transform array into a distribution?

Tags: python, seaborn, probability, distribution

I have an array, vox_betas, that contains 21600 floats (ranging from ~0 to ~2), and when sorted by the array, features, you can see that there is a structure to the data (see 1st pic).

I want to have a single array that reflects this structure -- essentially I want to call sns.distplot() and have that produce the same plot as the first picture. Right now sns.distplot(vox_betas) depicts the 2nd picture, which is not what I want.

I was able to accomplish this in the third picture by creating the array, dist, but the way I accomplished this was sloppy and even loses some information (my code is below).

How would you transform vox_betas and features into dist? Does anyone have any ideas?

```
plt.scatter(features,vox_betas)
```

[image]

```
sns.distplot(vox_betas)
```

[image]

```
dist=[]
for f in np.unique(features):
    dist = np.concatenate((dist,
                np.repeat(f,
                np.sum(
                [vox_betas[j]*10 for j in np.where(features==f)[0]]))))

sns.distplot(dist)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **[inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)**:

> is a basic method for pseudo-random number sampling, i.e., for
>   generating sample numbers at random from any probability distribution
>   given its [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

The best explanation I found is [this one](https://matlabtricks.com/post-44/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-distribution). Also discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321542/how-can-i-draw-a-value-randomly-from-a-kernel-density-estimate).

Comment: This is very similar to what I'm going after, so thanks for the note -- I had not previously heard of inverse transform sampling. However, I don't have a cumulative distribution function to transform here..

Comment: You can create the CDF from every distribution you have, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#common-methods

Comment: Or there are non build-in functions: https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/05/empirical-cumulative-distribution-function-ecdf-in-python/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640759/how-to-get-the-cumulative-distribution-function-with-numpy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788200/calculate-the-cumulative-distribution-function-cdf-in-python

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use `np.cumsum`.

Comment: You can also search for ECDF (empirical cumulative distribution function), e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ap4mfGvgDsM

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of ECDF!